# Insufficient memory. error al ejecutar opencv_traincascade con OpenCV 2.3.1 en Python 2.7 usando Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy siguiendo el ejemplo de: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

Casi todo me ha salido bien, en la parte donde fallo es cuando ejecuto el último paso, cuando intento crear el archivo .xml que me servirá para detectar mis propios objetos:

```
  opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt  -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000  -numNeg 600 -w 80 -h 40 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024  -precalcIdxBufSize 1024
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, me dice lo siguiente:

```
  PARAMETERS:
  cascadeDirName: classifier
  vecFileName: samples.vec
  bgFileName: negatives.txt
  numPos: 1000
  numNeg: 600
 numStages: 20
 precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 2048
 precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 2048
 stageType: BOOST
 featureType: HAAR
 sampleWidth: 80
 sampleHeight: 40
 boostType: GAB
 minHitRate: 0.999
 maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
 weightTrimRate: 0.95
 maxDepth: 1
 maxWeakCount: 100
 mode: ALL

  ===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
 <BEGIN
 POS count : consumed   1000 : 1000
 NEG count : acceptanceRatio    600 : 1
 OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 2147481604 bytes)  in OutOfMemoryError, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 52
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
 what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 2147481604 bytes in function OutOfMemoryError
```

Tengo en mi PC 3 GB de RAM, de la cual siempre al ejecutar este comando cierro todos los programas, quedando 2 GB de memoria RAM libre, pero ni aun así me salvo de este error.

Si conocen de otra manera para crear los haar cascade me la pueden mostrar, estoy abierto a cualquier alternativa que me muestren.

Comment: Deberías añadir el código que usas para tus cálculos en lugar de enlazar a un blog. En el blog que enlazas usan openCV desde perl y node pero etiquetas la pregunta con 'python'. Deberías intentar ayudar a los que les estás pidiendo ayuda :-)

Comment: @kikocorreoso lo siento mucho no me habia fijado en ese detalle, lo que paso es que en el ejemplo que sigo hay una parte que se hace con un script de python, pero si sabes como crear un haar cascade me la puedes ensenar estoy algo desesperado por que no me funciona. es cierto que el primer paso se hace con perl pero ya en el penultimo paso es con un script de python llamado mergevec.py

Comment: El error es claro, `Failed to allocate 2147481604 bytes`, intenta eliminar las imágenes/arrays que ya hayas usado, hazlo con imágenes más pequeñas o hazlo en un PC con más RAM. Creo que poco más puedes hacer.

Comment: @kikocorreoso tengo 169 imagenes positivas de las cuales no superan los 50kb cada una y las imagenes estan el escala de grises, ademas de imagenes negativas hay 497 que no superan ni los 55kb cada una para crear un haar cascade segun he investigado se necesita una gran cantidad de imagenes pero voy a recortar la cantidad de imagenes a 50 de cada carpeta(positiva  negativa a ver que como me va) asi que el problema es la ram, me lo imaginaba supongo que tendre que comprar una nueva pc como de cuanta ram me recomendarias? se que esto no forma parte de la pregunta principal, me gustaria saber?

Comment: @kikocorreoso que tanto sabes de opencv? me podrias ensenar a crear los haar cascade? se que no forma parte de la pregunta principal pero me gustaria saber eso, y muchas gracias por estar pendiente de responder mis preguntas

Comment: Si las imágenes son de ese tamaño, alguna otra cosa debes estar haciendo (operaciones intermedias) que te suba tanto la RAM pero es difícil de saber sin ver el código. Respecto a tutoriales, [aquí tienes uno](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/), [aquí otro](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html) y este [otro blog es excelente para aprender a usar openCV](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/06/20/detecting-cats-in-images-with-opencv/).

Comment: @kikocorreoso yo he seguido los pasos de el blog ademas en el ultimo link que me pasas solo muestran detectar gatos no ensenan a crear los haar cascade, pero en fin he notado un detalle en mi pc que cuando ejecuto el comando la memoria ram sube rapidamente pero cuando la terminal acapara 700mb de espacio se detiene la terminal y me lanza ese mensaje lo raro es que viendo al mismo tiempo el monitor de sistema es que al momento de cerrarse la terminal el sistema aun tiene casi 2gb libres

Comment: Te he puesto tres enlaces, no uno, en todos hablan de Haar cascades, en el de los gatos usan lo que viene por defecto en OpenCV, uno definido para gatos, en el primero te enseñan desde cero a detectar tus propios objetos. Respecto a la memoria, seguramente, cuando te muestra el MemoryError es cuando usa un pico de memoria que no llega a mostrarse en el monitor del sistema. Es difícil aportar más información si no muestras el código. donde se produce el error.

Comment: opencv_traincascade -data classifier -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.txt  -numStages 20 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 1000  -numNeg 600 -w 80 -h 40 -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024  -precalcIdxBufSize 1024 @kikocorreoso es en esta linea en el blog estan todos los pasos lo que pasa es que el ultimo paso en donde falla